# Changing index.js entryFile to index.android.js throws error

Tags: android, react-native

I'm starting with `react-native` and created a basic project. That contained `index.js` in its root. I wanted to make for android and after going through few tutorials renamed `index.js` to `index.android.js` and also following change in `/android/app/build.gradle`

```
project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.android.js"
]
```

Still I always get the following error:

[image]

Do I need to change the entry file elsewhere?I've run `node start --reset-cache` as well.

Comment: Did you rebuild your app? Usinh react-native run-android

Comment: @Prince Yes, of course. after building only I'm getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest version of React-Native Cli, The index.js is common file for both android and ios.

In the latest version, if you this in terminal

```
react-native init Demo1
```

The project structure will look somewhat like the below one.

[image: Demo1]

You don't have to rename it.

If you do

```
react-native run-android
```

or

```
react-native run-android
```

or 
 **run it from android studio after build**

This should work perfectly

[image: Demo1 ios]

Comment: Thats right. It runs without renaming. But I was trying to find a procedure to rename it and make it working. I expect there to be some way of renaming `index.js` to OS specific ex. `index.android.js` and changing some settings should work.

Comment: Just Suggesting a work around. If you want you make it OS specific. You can do it by verifying the Platform. Check if `if(Platform.OS=='android') { return <YourAndroidComponent />} else { return <YourIOSComponent  />} `. in your index.js